# How to save the date and hour as a text automatically in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I want to get the last time another cell was changed (i.e. a value has been entered in a cell or modified).

I know there are shortcuts to obtain the current time:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> **:** Insert the current date.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> **:** Insert the current time.

The purpose of this question is to know if any of you knows how to automate this process in an effectively way, thus I would avoid losing time  pressing 5 keys everytime I want to save the current time in a cell.

I'm making a list of new English words, so I want to save, in a cell, the time a cell is modified. In the following link you can see an image of my list and some examples of how I've been storing the time using the shortcuts:

[image: worksheet]

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**Edit 1:** Shortcut (used to insert the current time) fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your picture, I assume that whenever a word in entered or modified in column **A**, the date should appear in column **B** and the time in column **C**.

Install the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range

    Set A = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count)

    If Intersect(A, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
        Target.Offset(0, 2) = Time
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**